# LIMIT clause on DELETE Query with Sub Query

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error when trying to run this query:

```
delete a from db.tablea a where a.id in (select id from db2.ids) limit 10000;
```

Can someone advise a way to rework this query and provide this same logic?

Comment: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` generally does not make any sense.  With regard to _which_ column values do you want to delete only 10000 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the multi-table syntax, which allows joins (and deleting from any of the joined tables) but not limit.  Use the single table syntax instead:

```
delete from db.tablea where id in (select id from db2.ids) limit 10000;
```

Comment: Thanks I had to remove the aliases to get it to work so delete from tablea where id in (select id from db2.ids) limit 1000 worked